# Elasticsearch custom separators for the standard analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

It is possible to provide a custom list of separators for the `standard` analyzer?

My application provides an element dropdown where I can select `dog,cat,mouse` and use this value as filter for searching. I want to be able to select dog, or cat, or mouse as filter values. Note that comma isn't the only separator for this element field. I could also have `dog&cat` or `dog<br>cat` or `dog;cat;mouse`

**Fields mapping:**

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "element": {
            "type": "text",
        }
        ................
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [char_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) which can replace a particular character to some other character, elasticsearch already break on `,` `&` and for others(which are not the delimiter) you can define them in char_filter.

You can also use the Analyze API as shown below to see whether char_filter is properly replacing your delimiter or not.

As `<br>` is a HTML code and standard analyzer will create a token for it, you can use the `html_strip` char_filter as shown below:

```
{
  "tokenizer" : "standard",
  "filter" : ["lowercase"],
  "char_filter" : ["html_strip"],
  "text" : "dog<br>cat"
}


{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "dog",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "cat",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```